# Quickblox Chat stopped working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, quickblox, quickblox-android

My app was working fine but Quicblox chat stopped working now 
 - I have quiclblox installed through Pods   - QuickBlox (2.8.0.1)
 (EDIT: Just updated the pod to Quickblox 2.9, but still the same)

Here's the code I have to send the message which still executes fine (with no error returned in sendMessage-block's response,) but the message don't goes through:

```
QBChatMessage * messageToSend = [QBChatMessage message];
messageToSend.recipientID = self.mRecieverQBUser.ID;
messageToSend.text = message;
messageToSend.senderID = SharedChatHelper.sharedHelper.qbUser.ID;
messageToSend.customParameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1", @"save_to_history", @"1", @"send_to_chat", nil];
messageToSend.dialogID = self.mDialogObject.ID;
[self.mDialogObject sendMessage:messageToSend completionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
}];
```

where mDialogObject is object of QBChatDialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Quickblox server was down for a couple of days in last week.
It's back working now.